# Chromecast Video playback stalls with buffering for MPEG-DASH Live streaming

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

1. Cast the following Live MPEG-DASH video using a Sender App (on Chrome browser) & Sample Custom Receiver App CastReferencePlayer to Chromecast :

http://vm2.dashif.org/livesim-dev/segtimeline_1/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd

2.Observe that Video stalls after a few seconds of playback with buffering indication

3. Chromecast receiver console log continuously displays the following message :

media_player.js:22  [ 12.134s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://vm2.dashif.org/livesim-dev/segtimeline_1/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd -1]
media_player.js:22  [ 12.137s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false

Additional Information :
Chromecast Firmware Version: 48342.
I have also submitted a Ticket : Issue 780. 
Such issue was reported for HLS Playback (Issue 646, 638), but it looks like it was resolved after some encoder settings were modified.
However, in the present case, a reference DASH Player plays this stream continuously without any issues. Issue is only on Chromecast.

Comment: Stumbled upon this issue as well. Thanks for the [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=780), seems that this is now a confirmed bug.

Comment: They have 'acknowledged' the issue. I'm eagerly awaiting further updates !